# Помощь с Split С#

Tags: c#, split

У меня есть длинная строка, в которой есть переходы на новую строку, вопросительные, восклицательные знаки, точки.
Мне нужно получить массив строк, которые будут делиться по правилу,

```
String[] lines = myText.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n', '.', '!', '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Такое решение делит всё верно, но проблема в том, что оно удаляет знаки препинания. Я хотел бы оставлять '.', '!', '?' вот эти знаки и удалять переходы на новую строку \r, \n.
Пример:

```
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, elit. Nullam! Faucibus congue?
Phasellus molestie, orci
Ut aliquam nulla tristique nec?
Nec bibendum tortor sodales!
```

Результат

```
1-Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, elit.
2-Nullam!
3-Faucibus congue?
4-Phasellus molestie, orci
5-Ut aliquam nulla tristique nec?
6-Nec bibendum tortor sodales!
```

Всем большое спасибо! Все ответы рабочие:)

Comment: "оставлять" - где?

Comment: В массиве строк. В данном случае lines.

Comment: Вы партизан? Оставлять как отдельные строки или как части получившихся при делении строк?

Comment: Как отдельные, конечно)

Comment: Xom9ik, вы хотите получить кучу отдельных знаков препинания в массиве? То есть из строки "Слово! снова слово?" должен получиться массив ["Слово", "!", "снова слово", "?"] ?

Comment: Нет. Если рассматривать Ваш пример, то  ["Слово!", "снова слово?"]

Comment: @Xom9ik, товарищу Igor вы ответили иначе)

Comment: Значит не так понял, прошу прощения. Нужно было сразу приводить пример)

Comment: @Xom9ik так добавьте в вопрос подробный пример

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Сначала подготавливаем текст, добавляя в знаки !?. `\n`.

```
var prepair = myText.Replace(".",".\n").Replace("!","!\n").Replace("?","?\n");

String[] lines = prepair.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Небольшое замечание. Replace в C# пишется с большой буквы. Поправьте пожалуйста. Так как данный пример не скомпилируется.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @СергейИгнахин спасибо.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин , пожалуйста)

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разделим текст с помощью регулярки:

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, elit. Nullam! Faucibus congue?\r\nPhasellus molestie, orci\r\nUt aliquam nulla tristique nec?\r\nNec bibendum tortor sodales!";
string pattern = @"((?<=[.?!])|\r?\n) *";
foreach (string s in Regex.Split(text, pattern).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Правда, придется удалить пустые строки вручную (я делаю это с помощью `Where`), так как в `Regex.Split()` нету аналога `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Здесь паттерн описывает формат разделителя:

`(?<=[.?!])` - положительный просмотр назад, т.е. ищем один из символов `.` или `?` или `!`, но они сами в разделитель не входят, они войдут в часть *перед разделителем*

`\r?\n` - перевод строки, поддерживает варианты как `\r\n`, так и просто `\n`

`|` - "или", т.е. разделитель удовлетворяет или одному шаблону, или другому

`*` - и любое число пробелов, они будут принадлежать разделителю и в результат не попадут